# How to beautify respond body of XHR (Ajax call) in Chrome browser?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

As can be seen in the screencast below, the respond body is a minified JSON object.. Does anyone have ideas about how to beautify it in Google Chrome Browser?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a valid `"application/json"` `content-type` specified for chrome to give you the collapsible drop-down

To see a tree view in recent versions of Chrome:

```
Navigate to Developer Tools > Network > the given response > Preview
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do it* with existing DevTools functionality.

Should be doable in an extension though (that adds another panel to Dev Tools), see [`chrome.devtools.network`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network) and in general ["Extending DevTools" guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools).

* See [ankur-singhal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28295194/934239) for an exception

Answer (score 0):

I found an extension called `JsonView`..

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc/related

It is awesome to beatify the JSON if it is available GET method.. but not sure how to access with POST method..